# how to resolve useEffect eslint dependency warning?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint, use-effect, react-state

I have a stateObject that I am changing in my useEffect. I only want it to work when loading changes.
but I am recieving a eslint warning to add mobile object in depency array or remove the dependency array.

My question is should I ignore the warning and disable it or I am doing something wrong, if I am how can I correct it?

here is my use effect

```
useEffect(() => {

    if (!loading) {
      setData({
        model: mobile.model,
        name: mobile.name,
        network: mobile.network,
        price: mobile.price,
        description: mobile.description,
      });
    }
  }, [loading]);
```

Comment: I think the right approach would be to call `setData` at the same time you call `setLoading` instead of using an effect hook

Comment: loading is coming from a different component in redux where I do not have access to this data.

Comment: Interesting. Would adding it to the dependency array break your app, or only result in unnecessary rerenders?

Comment: From what I see, `mobile` ***is*** a dependency. Why are you omitting it? Or why do you think including it is an issue?

Comment: @CertainPerformance adding mobile to the dependency array, keeps the data object equal to mobile values. whenever I call setData it re-renders and values change back to mobile values. Whereas removing mobile form the dependency array gives me the desired result by giving data the mobile values when loading becomes false and after which I can change these values as long as loading doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is should I ignore the warning and disable it or I am
> doing something wrong, if I am how can I correct it?

This is a subjective question but generally you should include all dependencies the linter complains about. There are exceptions to this though, for example, when wanting an effect to run only once when the component mounts. You can OFC omit any dependencies you like, ***if*** you really know what you are doing, but be aware that the linter will complain about missing dependencies or silently ignore them if you disable the linting rule for that line.

From what I see, `mobile` ***is*** a dependency and should be included.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!loading) {
    setData({
      model: mobile.model,
      name: mobile.name,
      network: mobile.network,
      price: mobile.price,
      description: mobile.description,
    });
  }
}, [loading, mobile]);
```

> I have a stateObject that I am changing in my useEffect. I only want
> it to work when loading changes.

The `if (!loading)` check ensures that `setData` is only called when loading changes ***and*** evaluates true. Including `mobile` in the dependency array ensures when `setData` *is* called that it has the latest value.